# how do I connect to mysql database from visual studio without requiring SSL connection?

Tags: mysql-5.7

I have established a link between Mysql database and visual studio on my windows 10 machine.Unfortunately my application which is a desktop app can't open a connection to the DB. I keep getting this error whenever I try connecting to the database:
**MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'The host localhost does not support SSL connections.'**

This is my connection:

***MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("user id=root;server=localhost;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=edutechsys");
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TblLogin WHERE UserName = '" + TxtUserName.Text.Trim() + "' and Password = '" + TxtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'");
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            **

How do I correct the error.

Comment: you might want to explicitly add this to the connection string - "SslMode=none"  Your connection should look like this:        ***MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("user id=root;server=localhost;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=edutechsys"); SslMode=none; MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TblLogin WHERE UserName = '" + TxtUserName.Text.Trim() + "' and Password = '" + TxtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'"); conn.Open(); cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); DataTable dt = new DataTable(); MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(); **

Answer (score 0):

You might want to explicitly add this to the connection string - "SslMode=none" 
Your connection should look like this:

> MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("user id=root;server=localhost;persistsecurityinfo=True;database=edutechsys"); **SslMode=none;** MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM
>   TblLogin WHERE UserName = '" + TxtUserName.Text.Trim() + "' and
>   Password = '" + TxtPassword.Text.Trim() + "'"); conn.Open();
>   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>   MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter();